# R vs. Matlab: Explanation for speed difference for rnorm, qnorm and pnorm functions

Tags: performance, r, matlab, runtime, rcpp

I compared the performance of the inbuilt R functions `rnorm`, `qnorm` and `pnorm` to the equivalent Matlab functions.

It seems as if the `rnorm` and `pnorm` functions are 3-6 times slower in R than in Matlab, whereas the `qnorm` function is ca. 40% faster in R. I tried the Rcpp package to speed up the R functions by using the corresponding C libraries which resulted in a decrease in runtime by ~30% which is still significantly slower than Matlab for `rnorm` and `pnorm`.

Is there a package availabe which provides a faster way of simulating normally distributed random variables in R (other than using the standard `rnorm` function)?

Comment: you've probably figured this out already, but the other thing to note is that picking big block of random numbers is *much* faster in R than picking them one-by-one ... i.e. `rnorm(1e6)` is much faster than `vapply(seq(1e6),function(i) rnorm(1),numeric(1))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To promote my comment to an answer: yes, there is.

`library("sos"); findFn("Ziggurat")` finds the  [rziggurat](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/SuppDists/html/ziggurat.html) function in the `SuppDists` package; it is implemented in C (or C++?), and its documentation says

> This implementation running in R is approximately three times as
>        fast as rnorm().

The other point to note, which may make as much or more difference in practice, is that picking big block of random numbers is much faster in R than picking them one-by-one ... i.e. `rnorm(1e6)` is much faster than `vapply(seq(1e6),function(i) rnorm(1),numeric(1))`

```
 library("SuppDists")
 library("rbenchmark")
 n <- 1e5
 benchmark(rziggurat(n),
          rnorm(n),
          vapply(seq(n),function(x) rnorm(1),numeric(1)))

##           test   elapsed   relative user.self
## 2     rnorm(n)     1.138     13.233     1.140
## 1 rziggurat(n)     0.086      1.000     0.088
## 3  vapply(...)    29.043    337.709    29.046
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for this hint! It actually improves the runtime by a factor of 6 on my machine. Maybe there is another package which also improves the runtime for the pnorm function?

Comment: Note that that Ziggurat implementation works only on 32-bit OSs. I put  something better onto CRAN earlier this year in [RcppZiggurat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.ziggurat.html).

Answer (score 10):

I see two distinct issues here, one in each paragraph:

- Yes, there are difference between languages / systems such as R and Matlab. Part of it has to do with the interpreter, speed of loops, speed of function calls etc pp.  Rcpp can help there with respect to Matlab which has a genuine JIT compiler.  We have a comparison between Matlab, R and R+Rcpp for a Kalman filter in the recent paper on RcppArmadillo.
- There also are difference in the underlying compiled code, and yes, R does not always have the faster implementation as R Core (IMHO rightly) goes for precision first. (And Rcpp does not help per se: We just call what R has internally.) This had come up eg with the Gibbs Sampler example for MCMC which Darren Wilkinson started. I noticed that R's `rgamma()` is much slower than other systems.  So to get to your question regarding N(0,1) draws in a faster way:  I think we need a contributed Ziggurat implementation.  That is one of the faster N(0,1) generators out there, and a few other systems use it.

Comment: Indeed: `library("sos"); findFn("Ziggurat")` finds http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/SuppDists/html/ziggurat.html , which says " This implementation running in R is approximately three times as fast as rnorm(). "

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I think I once I knew that but filed it under "good, and now I need it from C++..." and forgot.

Comment: Yep -- Ziggurat goes back to a JSS paper and free implementation.  Matter of available time and other projects...

Comment: (Coming back to this months later:) I actually released a package [RcppZiggurat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.ziggurat.html) earlier this year.